# Dynamically provide awsconfiguration while uploading files using TransferUtility

Tags: android, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

**Current Implementation**

I have implemented file upload functionality using `AWS Mobile SDK` and according to their documentation, we have to store an `awsconfiguration.json` file (this file contains `CognitoIdentity`,`IdentityManager` & `S3TransferUtility`) and we create an instance of `TransferUtility` like this for uploading :

```
TransferUtility transferUtility = TransferUtility.builder()
            .context(getApplicationContext())
            .awsConfiguration(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getConfiguration())
            .s3Client(new AmazonS3Client(AWSMobileClient.getInstance()))
            .build();
```

This implementation works great when we have just one `AWS Instance`

**Required Implementation**

I have a requirement where i have to implement this for more than one `AWS Instance`. To explain better, we have more than one AWS account for different clients and each account will have their own s3 bucket.

Now i have to upload files based on the type of client i logged in within my app. This means that their `awsconfiguration.json` file will be different for each client.

**Question**

Is there any method by which i can dynamically generate awsconfiguration.json or better yet, pass values for fields like CognitoIdentity & S3TransferUtility when uploading file?

Comment: You required all the values from `awsconfiguration.json` on your end??

Comment: yeah atleast `CognitoIdentity` & `S3TransferUtility` and their sub fields are needed

Comment: You can manually configure your aws without the json file as well. Which you can make dynamic for your multiple accounts.

Comment: @SavinSharma If that is possible, can you please post the code snippet or share a link where i can find this solution?

Comment: I have shared a code snippet which I have used for my aws upload part.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the aws configuration manually without using the `awsconfiguration.json`

**build.gradle**

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.6.+'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.+'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.6.+'
```

**This is for ClientConfiguration part of AWS**

```
ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
clientConfiguration.setMaxErrorRetry(0);
clientConfiguration.setConnectionTimeout(3600000);
clientConfiguration.setSocketTimeout(3600000);
```

> This is your CongnitoIdentity Part

Now get the `bucketNameS3`, `accessKey` and `secretKey` from some api which you can set dynamic for dynamic account.

```
String bucketNameS3 = "something";
String accessKey = "something";
String secretKey = "something";
```

Set all this value in `BasicAWSCredentials` object like

```
BasicAWSCredentials basicAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
```

**Next step is your `AmazonS3Client` object**

```
AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(basicAWSCredentials, clientConfiguration);
```

Here you can add the `Regions` to your `AmazonS3Client` you just have to create the object and pass it in your `amazonS3Client`.

**Regions**

```
Regions regions = Regions.fromName("your region name");
amazonS3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(regions));
```

> Your TransferUtility Part

```
TransferUtilityOptions options = new TransferUtilityOptions();
options.setTransferThreadPoolSize(1);
options.setTransferServiceCheckTimeInterval(30 * 1000); // 30-second
TransferUtility transferUtility = TransferUtility.builder()
                        .context(getApplicationContext())
                        .s3Client(amazonS3Client)
                        .transferUtilityOptions(options)
                        .defaultBucket(bucketNameS3)
                        .build();
```

Comment: Do you have a link from where you got this solution? If yes, please post it as well

Comment: Actually i don't have the link because i did this few months back. I referred the official doc of amazon s3 at that time.

Comment: Ok. I was going through your solution and i didn't find any way to add `PoolId` and `Region` which is inside `Default` JsonObject of `CognitoIdentity`

Comment: I have mentioned how you can add `Region` in your `amazonS3Client`.